# What's the purpose of the decoration on the BrickHeadz piece?

Tags: piece-information, piece-usage

I just bought a BrickHeadz set (the Captain America one) and it comes with a piece to put on the models base. The part number is 6188632 and is described on a few sites as a black 2x4 with decoration. What I don't get is what the purpose of the decoration is. Here is a picture of the piece.

[image]

The decoration looks like a generic BrickHeadz head with a speech bubble with the number one. So is that all there really is to it or is there something I'm missing? I thought it might represent the models number but this particular one is number five in the series not one.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to LEGO, it's the BrickHeadz icon with the series number.

> He also stands on a buildable baseplate with series number and BrickHeadz icon for easy display -- [Batman Brickheadz LEGO Shop page](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Batman-41585)

If they release another series of Brickheadz, those sets will probably have a similar piece with a "2" on it.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Not the model in the series but the series itself! How silly.